# How to test success and error cases of an observable subscription

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My goal is to unit test success and error cases of the function `getData()`. In success case, `this.success` function must have been called. In error case, `this.failure` function must have been called.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(): void {
  this.myService.getServiceData().subscribe( 
     //returns an observable
    (result) => {
      this.success(result);
    },
    error => {
      this.failure(error);
    }
  );
  }
}
```

This is my unit test:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component = MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let myService = jasmine.SpyObj<MyServiceClass>;

  beforeEach(async(()=> {
    myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyServiceClass', ['getServiceData']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: MyServiceClass, useValue: myService }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

  }));

  it('should call success function', async(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'success');
    myService.getServiceData.and.returnValue(asyncData(myMockObj));
    component.getData();
    //fails. If I expect failure() to be called, it ALSO fails!
    expect(component.success).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
})
```

asyncData function looks like that:

```
export function asyncData<T>(data: T) {
  return defer(() => Promise.resolve(data));
}
```

Why is it failing and how can I test those two cases?

Comment: What's the error? If it's an observable you can try myService.getServiceData.and.returnValue(of(myMockObj)); assuming you have myMockObject initilized somewhere.

Comment: The error is: Expected spy success to have been called. Same error with your suggestion. Same error if I expect function failure() to be called.

Comment: `createSpyObj` creates a spy that is not related to the service injected to the component. Therefore, it cannot have been called. Please share the code from your unit test that shows how the component is created.

Comment: Try to add `await` in front of the line `component.getData();`.

Comment: @uminder that solved my issue. Thanks.